# Writing HTML file with Java PrintWriter

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to write data to HTML file with Java PrintWriter:

```
String data = "<div>There is some text here</span>";
writer.print(data);
```

But when I open HTML file in browser I can see my text as:

```
<div>There is some text here</div>
```

The editor shows HTML file as:

```
&lt;div&gt;There is some text here&lt;/div&gt;
```

I also tried to write to HTML file like this:

```
String data = "&lt;div&gt;There is some text here&lt;/div&gt;";
writer.print(data);
```

but the browser displayed the file as:

```
&lt;div&gt;There is some text here&lt;/div&gt;
```

Could anybody explain who should I write data to HTML file to get the correct result>?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  If I write text to a file using a `PrintWriter`, then open the file and check its source, I see only what I wrote.  Is there some detail you've forgotten to tell us?

Comment: How are you instantiating the PrintWriter? Are you writing directly to a file, or to another outputstream?

Comment: Please try to write a MCVE(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to describe your question.

Answer (score 6):

Have you set the ContentType to text/html? Like below.

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print("<div>There is some text here</div>");
```

Comment: HttpServletResponse object reference.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment I made, you'd better write a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can locate to your question better. Also, provide the editor you are using and what's configuration you have made to your editor.

Based on the information you provided, to answer you question directly, you can use the `PrintWriter` like below,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            File file = new File("demo.html");
            String data = "<div>There is some text here</span>";
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It will generate `<div>There is some text here</span>` (You want to use div or span?) at demo.html on my environment. However, I can also convert the output to `&lt;div&gt;There is some text here&lt;/span&gt;` in my **editor**. So here comes the question, can you make sure it's not the problem of your editor? Let me show you how can I use my editor to show `<div>There is some text here</span>` as `&lt;div&gt;There is some text here&lt;/span&gt;`.

1. Use notepad++
2. Install "Html Tag" plugin
3. Select the html text --> Plugins --> Html Tag --> Encode entities